# Allure/TestNG/Maven: org.testng.ITestNGListener: Provider io.qameta.allure.testng.AllureTestNg could not be instantiated

Tags: maven, selenium, allure

I am trying to integrate Allure to my Maven project. Here's what I've done so far:
- Installed a commandline and set up the class path. As part of validation when I run allure --version in a console, I get a 2.4.1 back.
- I followed the instructions at  https://docs.qameta.io/allure/latest/#_testng and made changes to the POM as mentioned there. 
Here's my POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.testautomation</groupId>
<artifactId>com.testautomation.selenium</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>

    <suiteXmlFile>src/main/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
    <webdriver.chrome>src/main/resources/chromedriver.exe</webdriver.chrome>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
    <allure.version>1.5.4</allure.version>
    <!--<maven.surefire.plugin.version>2.20</maven.surefire.plugin.version>-->

</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-BETA19</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>

            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <webdriver.chrome.driver>${webdriver.chrome}</webdriver.chrome.driver>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                </argLine>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

But when I clean test, I get the below error:

```
[ERROR] There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] org.testng.ITestNGListener: Provider io.qameta.allure.testng.AllureTestNg could not be instantiated
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] org.testng.ITestNGListener: Provider io.qameta.allure.testng.AllureTestNg could not be instantiated
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:665)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:533)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:279)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:243)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1077)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:907)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:785)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
[ERROR] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR] at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
```

I checked online for solution and I ran into this page: https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-maven/issues/13 
And from the comments it seemed like an issue with my class path but not sure how to pin point the problem.

I tried clean test by commenting out the below dependency and my build succeeds and a sure-fire report is generated.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
    <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-BETA19</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

And I am able to generate an Allure report using the command line: allure serve ...\surefire-reports

Please let me know what I am doing wrong. 
Thanks!

Comment: Can you please help create a sample project and perhaps share it via github.com or bitbucket ? That way, I would be able to try out your project and recreate the issue. I tried creating a sample project at my end and tried building the project using maven. I cant reproduce it.

Comment: Thanks for the response @KrishnanMahadevan
I have committed my project at the below repo. Please take a look and let me know. Thanks! 
https://github.com/somethingfunny/AllureRepo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding the below dependency solved my issue.

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue when used below dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

But when I changed allure-testng dependency to 2.7.0 issue got resolved

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to lower `allure-testng` version helped me.

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
      <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```